# How to handle ListView click in Android

Tags: android, listview, click, onitemclicklistener

How do I listen to click event on a ListView?

This is what I have now

```
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);  
...  
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

When I do the following

```
list.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {  
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parentView, View childView, 
                                                         int position, long id) 
   {  
       setDetail(position);  
   }

   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parentView) {  

   }  
});
```

That doesn't seem to do anything on click.
And all those code live within a class that extends Activity.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

On your list view, use `setOnItemClickListener`

Comment: How do you then send data to that detailed view? (Like youtube clicking through to a video)

Comment: First, the class must implements the click listenener :

 implements OnItemClickListener
Then set a listener to the ListView

yourList.setOnItemclickListener(this);
And finally, create the clic method:

 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
 long id) {
 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " +countries[+ position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }

Answer (score 91):

Suppose ListView object is lv, do the following-

```
lv.setClickable(true);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

    Object o = lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
    /* write you handling code like...
    String st = "sdcard/";
    File f = new File(st+o.toString());
    // do whatever u want to do with 'f' File object
    */  
  }
});
```

Comment: `lv` is not accessible inside `onItemClick`. What's a nice way to get around that?

Comment: @shinjin Make it final. `final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_list_view);`

Comment: Clean way: `Object o = ((ListView)arg0).getItemAtPosition(position);`

Comment: Here is the link to the documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html

Answer (score 42):

You need to set the inflated view "Clickable" and "able to listen to click events" in your adapter class getView() method.

```
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_text, null);
convertView.setClickable(true);
convertView.setOnClickListener(myClickListener);
```

and declare the click listener in your ListActivity as follows,

```
public OnClickListener myClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
                 //code to be written to handle the click event
    }
};
```

This holds true only when you are customizing the Adapter by extending BaseAdapter.

Refer the ANDROID_SDK/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.java for more details

Comment: But this doesn't determine what item is being clicked, which makes it more-or-less useless for a list? Correct?

Comment: you can set tag to convertView and check the same in onClick.. using tag which item is clicked can be identified...

Comment: I have found a more elegant solution than a tag in your adapter store a setOnClickListener reference and call it on the onClick(View v) method. then the activity can recieve the event with the position.

Comment: Your onClick method is wrong.  It should be onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Its not wrong..!! it was another way to handle click event. though now its not recommended. [Android Docs] (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html). And what you are saying is already there in Aditya Mehta's answer.

Answer (score 17):

The two answers before mine are correct - you can use `OnItemClickListener`.

It's good to note that the difference between `OnItemClickListener` and `OnItemSelectedListener`, while sounding subtle, is in fact significant, as item selection and focus are related with the touch mode of your `AdapterView`.

By default, in touch mode, there is no selection and focus.
You can take a look [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/12/touch-mode.html) for further info on the subject.

Answer (score 8):

This solution is really minimalistic and doesn't mess up your code.

In your **list_item.xml** (NOT listView!) assign the attribute **android:onClick** like this:

```
<RelativeLayout android:onClick="onClickDoSomething">
```

and then in your activity call this method:

```
public void onClickDoSomething(View view) {
   // the view is the line you have clicked on
}
```

Comment: good solution but, there is no way to get position of item clicked

Comment: @BilalŞimşek For a long time I've been out of Android but if the `view` can have some metadata, it could be the way how to get the position.

Answer (score 7):

You have to use `setOnItemClickListener` someone said.
The code should be like this:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text or do whatever you need.
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

First, the class must implements the click listenener :

```
implements OnItemClickListener
```

Then set a listener to the ListView

```
yourList.setOnItemclickListener(this);
```

And finally, create the clic method:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
long id) {
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " +countries[+ position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

you can take a look and download code [here](http://www.bourax.com/ismaidro/index.php?controller=post&action=view&id_post=4)

Answer (score 3):

Use setOnItemClickListener() api in your activity. Following is the sample.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
     // your code here.
}

});
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin, add a listener to your listView as simple as java

```
your_listview.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->   

    Toast.makeText(this, position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

 }
```