# Listview click in Android

Tags: android, listview

I have programmed a ListView with some elements. Now I want to know which element was clicked. So that I can say, when the first was clicked, do this, the second, do that.

So how do I know which element the user clicked?

Thanks

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468100/android-listview-click-howto

Answer (score 0):

I have done it with the position of the element.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`setOnItemClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29). This is a pretty basic question. Google is your friend. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `list.setOnListItemClickListener` and use the `index` or `position` parameter that the listener passes :)