# setOnItemClickListener on Listview that extend activity

Tags: java, android, listview

**Update : I found the solution by 
removing**

`v.setFocusable(true);` 
`v.setClickable(true);` in the code

and only add

`v.setEnabled(true);`

and in my xml (ListView) add

`android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"`
`android:focusable="true"`

---

When I click it nothing happens , even the list view doesn't focus.

**I have tried to add all this:**

```
           v.setClickable(true);
           v.setEnabled(true); 
           v.setFocusable(true);
```

**Only this will work is i add the following code:**

But this doesn't determine what item is being clicked

[How to handle ListView click in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468100/android-listview-click-howto/2468155#2468155)

and the result still the same.

**Here's is the code :**

```
public class AppsInspectorActivity extends Activity {
     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
//[...]
    ListView app_listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);

// I try setOnItemClickListene here - 1
    app_listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I Clicked on Row " + position + ".", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
```

**Adapter**

```
 public class AppAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

            Context context;
            ArrayList<AppInfo> dataList=new ArrayList<AppInfo>();
            public AppAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<AppInfo> inputDataList)
            {

                this.context = context;
                dataList.clear();
                for(int i=0;i<inputDataList.size();i++)
                {
                    dataList.add(inputDataList.get(i));
                }
            }
            public int getCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return dataList.size();
            }

            public Object getItem(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return dataList.get(position);
            }

            public long getItemId(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return position;
            }

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                View v=convertView;
                final AppInfo appUnit = dataList.get(position);

                ListView app_listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);

                /** Remove this , i just try to add to see setOnItemClickListener will work at here or not **/
                 app_listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                      int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I Clicked on Row " + position + ".", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
                });

                if(v==null)
                {
                    LayoutInflater vi=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    v=vi.inflate(R.layout.app_row, null);
                    v.setClickable(true);
                    v.setEnabled(true); 
                    v.setFocusable(true);           
                }


                TextView appName=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.appName);
                ImageView appIcon=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.AppIcon);

                if(appName!=null)
                    appName.setText(appUnit.appName);
                if(appIcon!=null)
                    appIcon.setImageDrawable(appUnit.appIcon);
                return v;
            }
         }
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you see any listitem there in your listview?

Comment: yes , I can see but it can't focus and click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by removing

`v.setFocusable(true); v.setClickable(true); in the code`

and only add

`v.setEnabled(true);`

and in my xml (ListView) add

`android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" android:focusable="true"`

Answer (score 1):

Can you please post the `main.xml` layout. Seems to me that you have another view on top of the listview that is consuming the touch events.

Answer (score 0):

Hi remove the setOnItemClickListener in the getView of the Adapter.Refer this [listView](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html)

Answer (score 0):

use `AppsInspectorActivity.this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`

```
  public class AppsInspectorActivity extends Activity {
     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
//[...]
    ListView app_listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);

// I try setOnItemClickListene here - 1
    app_listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(AppsInspectorActivity.this, "I Clicked on Row " + position + ".", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
```

and remove the `setOnItemClickListener` from the `getView()` method in your adapter

Comment: Result still the same even setOnItemClickListener moved to onCreate

Answer (score 0):

Change your `getView()` to below one and tell if it works

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View v=convertView;
            final AppInfo appUnit = dataList.get(position);
            if(v==null)
            {
                LayoutInflater vi=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v=vi.inflate(R.layout.app_row, null);
                v.setClickable(true);
                v.setEnabled(true); 
                v.setFocusable(true);           
            }


            TextView appName=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.appName);
            ImageView appIcon=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.AppIcon);

            if(appName!=null)
                appName.setText(appUnit.appName);
            if(appIcon!=null)
                appIcon.setImageDrawable(appUnit.appIcon);
            return v;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set adapter to listview before setting its onItemClick.Here you just get the listview but with no items.so when you click on listview,its onItemClick is never called.

Comment: But I do get the listview with items