# How can I make the my listview interactive?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android - ListView click HOWTO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468100/android-listview-click-howto)

to be more specific I have a list of Restaurants in a list view and I want to click on a restaurant in the list then be directed to another list that has the menu for that resturan
thanks

Comment: there are literally thousand of examples all over the internet, and even in the android developer website

Comment: please give me one clear example of what I need, I only need one, Thanks a lot @njzk2

Comment: please do a bit of personal research before asking for a pre-made answer

Comment: You could have performed a search to find this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2468100/1329524

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list_view);
 listView.setAdapter(someAdapter);
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch(position) {
            case 0:
                 Intent intent = new Intent();
                 intent.setClassName("com.test", "com.test.SubMenuActivity");
                 startActivity(intent);             
                 break;
            case 1:
                 // Do something else ...
                 break;
            // ... 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Wire up the `onItemClickListener` on the list object.

Comment: @njzk2 - thanks - don't have my android IDE to hand.

Comment: if you could give me an example it would be much appreciated thanks!

Comment: If you are using the Android SDK in Eclipse, just start typing and it will offer suggestions on how to do it...