# On a ListView item's child click

Tags: android, listview, children, onitemclicklistener

I have a ListView where each of its items is composed from some `ImageViews` and `TextViews`,
i want that when i click on a specefic `ImageView`, some code will be executed, where should i put this code is it in `onItemClick` method?

```
public class EspaceClientUplodedProducts extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

List<Produit> lesProduits= new ArrayList<Produit>();
ListView lvListe;
ProductsDataSource produitSource;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.espaceclientuploads);

    produitSource=new ProductsDataSource(this);
    produitSource.open();
    lesProduits=produitSource.getAllUploads();

    lvListe= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.UploadListView);
    UploadedAdapter adapter = new UploadedAdapter(this, lesProduits);
    lvListe.setAdapter(adapter);
    lvListe.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}



@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
{

}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    produitSource.close();
    super.onPause();
}
```

the getView code:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView==null)
    {
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.espaceclientuploadsource, null);
        holder.nomduProduit = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.UploadedProductName);
        holder.prixDuProduit = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.UplodedProductPrice);
        holder.imageDuProduit = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Uplodimage);
        holder.status = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.UploadedStatus);
        holder.delete=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ImageViewDelete);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }

    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path+File.separator+lesProduits.get(position).getImage());

    Drawable drawableImage = new BitmapDrawable(bitmapImage);
    holder.imageDuProduit.setImageDrawable(drawableImage);
    holder.nomduProduit.setText(lesProduits.get(position).getNomDuProduit());
    holder.prixDuProduit.setText(lesProduits.get(position).getPrixDuProduit());
    holder.delete.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete);

    switch (lesProduits.get(position).getStatus())
    {

    case 3://annonce Accepté
    holder.status.setImageResource(R.drawable.accepte); 
    break;

    case 2://annonce en Attente
    holder.status.setImageResource(R.drawable.enattente);   
    break;

    case 1://annonce refusé
    holder.status.setImageResource(R.drawable.refuse);
    break;

    case 0://produit vendu
    holder.status.setImageResource(R.drawable.vendu);
    break;
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468100/android-listview-click-howto
When you get your object you could check for the position or something else and do what you want

Comment: I got the same answer from 'Md Abdul gafur' but that's not what i'm looking for, i have a code that i want it to be executed when i click on a specefic component of the item, like when i click on the ImageView called 'Delete' the item should be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `UploadedAdapter` in `getView()` you must be creating the object of the `ImageViews`.

Just set the `onClickListener` to the objects of that `ImageViews` and handle the click event in the `onClick` on the basis of the id of each `ImageView`.

Comment: Yeah i already have an object for my imageView in the get view method.
I can't understant the second part of your answer, if you can put some code it will be helpfull.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say your `getView` has a `textView` and a `imageView`:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.xml, parent, false);
    // setup view bindings
    TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    setClickListener(textView, position, parent);
    setClickListener(imageView, position, parent);
}
    
private void setClickListener(View view, final int position, final ViewGroup parent){
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // this part is important, it lets ListView handle the clicks
            ((ListView) parent).performItemClick(v, position, 0);
        }
    });
}
```

Now in `Activity` or `Fragment`:

```
ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        long viewId = view.getId();
        if (viewId == R.id.textView) {
            Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "TextView Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (viewId == R.id.imageView) {
            Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "ImageView Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You put this code in

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
{

}
```

or you can write something like that

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
          int position, long id) {
        final String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        view.animate().setDuration(2000).alpha(0)
            .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                list.remove(item);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                view.setAlpha(1);
              }
            });
      }

    });
```

Comment: Sorry but i want to get clicks on a specefic component of my ListView Item.

Comment: can you try second method.