# How do I add Click Listener to ListView?

Tags: android

I have a List View which is populated with countries I want to be able to click a an item and have it go to another activity in which i play an audio.
my list View:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item,getResources()
    .getStringArray(R.array.countries)));
     }
    }
```

How do I go about adding a onClick just like how you would make one for a button??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle ListView click in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468100/how-to-handle-listview-click-in-android)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ListView listView = getListView(); // hear bind your listview

setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item,getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries)));

 listView.setAdapter(ListAdapter);
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View itemView, int itemPosition, long itemId)
        {           

        }
    });

 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Either** use `getListView()` to access built in list view, and operate on that:

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener();
```

**Or**, override `onListItemClicked()` in `ListActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    //--do stuff--
}
```

Answer (score 2):

override `onItemClick()` method

```
 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
              long arg3) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
     Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);
     startActivity(intent);

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your activity extends `ListActivity`

```
  ListView lv = getListView();
  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View itemView, int itemPosition, long itemId)
    {           
          Intent launchActivity = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
          startActivity(launchActivity);
    }
   });
```

Answer (score 2):

U can use context.getlistview() to get the listview. and add setOnItemClickListener to the listview like this.

```
context.getlistview().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //Do whatever you want here

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

To make it handy just `implement OnItemClickListener` to your class

Add this in `onCreate`

```
ListView listView = getListView();
listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

then override `onItemClick` like this

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id){
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the setOnItemClickListener method.
Here is the code

```
 listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // do your code here

        }
    });
```