# could not set a onclicklistener for a list view

Tags: android

I have no idea how to set a `onclicklistener` for a item in listview.  I tried to find some samples or ask someone but nothing worked.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Please provide some of what you have tried, and what context you need to create one.

Comment: Do a simple google/stackoverflow search before asking such a basic question. The internet is full of ListView examples and your answer is already here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468100/android-listview-click-howto

Comment: `Can anybody help me?` **Yes**. Google can.

Answer (score 0):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //clickItemLogic();

            }
        });
```