# Handle ListView/ListViewItem click in layout.xml onClick

Tags: android, listview

Usually, I assign button click handler as follows-

```
//activity_main.xml
<Button android:onClick="DoWork" />

//MainActivity.java
public void DoWork(View view){}
```

Now, I have got a ListView which click event handler is as the following-

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.CategoryListView);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id)
        {

        }
    });
}
```

If I would like to do `<ListView android:onClick="Something"/>` , how should I define the method?

Sorry if this is a foolish question. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to handle an item click or the whole listview click?

Comment: I think it is impossible. You can set listener to your list items, not to your `listView`

Comment: Its not possible for Listview.. but you can set onClick for listview itme

Comment: @Mehta, Well, then suggest for item.

Comment: Item means listview child..  and handle  click event in your adapter

Comment: @Nikola, Just an item click, not the entire listview.

Comment: I think you code the onclick in the view that is displayed/viewed by the listview. i.e. within the layout that is called by the listview's adapter. (only done this with custom adapters).

Comment: e.g. I have the following `<TextView
            android:id="@+id/shoppinglist_donebutton"
            style="@style/textviewbutton"
            android:text="@string/shoppinglistpurchasedbutton"
            android:onClick="sledone"/>`. This is in shopping_list_entry, which is invoked by `public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.shopping_list_entry, parent, false);` This is within the adapter used by the Listview. The method (sledone) is within the activity that invokes Listview.

Comment: Oops sorry, that was for a view within the item. It's easier, you just code onclick="yourmethod" and include the method in the activity. If you code the method first then Studio will display that method when you input onclick (at least it does for me).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - ListView click HOWTO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468100/android-listview-click-howto)