# Kotlin - Start new activity after click on ListView record

Tags: listview, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to create a method to start new activity after clicked on record in ListView. Can you show how to do this?

Comment: [Start new activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html), [How to handle ListView click in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468100/how-to-handle-listview-click-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lv.setClickable(true)
lv.setOnItemClickListener(object : AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

        override fun onItemClick(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
                    //start activity here
        }
    })
```